# Sass/Ruby error when @import compass

Tags: ruby, import, sass, compass-sass, compass

I've installed sass and compass - the compass watch and compile are working fine, but the `@import "compass/reset";` in the screen.scss gives this error:

> C:/Ruby193/bin/scss.bat --no-cache --update screen.scss:screen.css
>         error screen.scss (Line 6: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/reset. Load paths:   )

Tried also @import "compass/css3" but gives the same error.

Tried uninstall and reinstall of both sass and compass, then I read something about incompatible versions so tried just installing compass on its own. I'm not familiar with ruby so would appreciate help with what to try next.

Versions:
ruby 1.9.3p125
Sass 3.4.5
Compass 1.0.1
Windows 7
Phpstorm 7.1

Comment: Did you create a Compass project?

Comment: @cimmanon I created it but didn't re-create it though after uninstalling & reinstalling. Would this make a difference? (I'm working with a lot of files so didn't want to delete and start again unless I had to!). EDIT: Now testing with a test project as it's taking too long anyway...will update later. Thanks for your comment.